# How to get data from an array in vb

Tags: arrays, vb.net

How do I get data from an array and display it or use it in a calculation if my array is like this.

```
Dim decRates(,) As Decimal = {{7,14.5}, {10, 15.5}, {12, 17.0}}
```

like if I wanted to assign `14.5` from this array to the variable `decCost`. Would I go:

```
decCost = decRates(0,1)
```

Comment: Please start with setting `Option Strict On`. It'll make you a better programmer. Your line `Dim decRates(,) As Decimal = {{7,14.5}, {10, 15.5}, {12, 17.0}}` doesn't compile when strict is on - which is what should happen.

Comment: And why haven't you tested you hypothesis? Run your code and find out if it works. Why are you asking us to do it?

Comment: currently away and cannot access a windows computer to use visual studios, as I only have a Mac

Comment: Try using https://dotnetfiddle.net to test your code when you only have a web browser.

Comment: Offtopic: @Enigmativity Thank you for this tipp with this web side. Now I don't have to open my playground-project every time I just want to test a little piece of code :D

Comment: @Horitsu - I'd also suggest getting http://www.linqpad.net - that's an even more awesome tool. I use it for most of my coding these days.

Comment: @Enigmativity Wow, that tool will become handy. Thank you very much for that tipp! It is just that nice tool to play with at testing new EntityFramework and LINQ stuff. I'm absolutely thrilled right now!